# Twitter Bootstrap - On collapse, the navbar options do not turn into a button that shows the options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this markup:

```
<div class='navbar'>
            <div class='navbar-inner'>
              <div class='container'>
                <a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                  <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </a>
                <div class='nav-collapse'>
                  <ul class='nav'>
                    <li class='active'>
                      <a href='#'>Home</a>
                      <a href='#'>Option 2</a>
                      <a href='#'>Option 3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It renders ok when the screen is full, but when I collapse the screen, it does not show the button which expands to show the options.  Is there something I am not doing correctly? Any idea why the button is not being shown after screen collapse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `bootstrap-responsive.css` stylesheet in order for the responsive feature to work.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 8):

As Andres said, you need to ensure that you include `bootstrap-responsive.cs`. You also need to make sure that you load the `bootstrap.js` file so that clicking on the collapsed button shows the menu list.

Additionally, you should wrap each link in its own `<li>` tag, like so:

```
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>    
  <li><a href='#'>Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Option 3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Otherwise you'll get a strange looking menu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the collapse plugin js file. like so: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html